# Is it possible to populate a DropDownListFor if the model returned to the View is an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm obviously missing something.

I thought populating a DropDownListFor would be as easy as returning a list from the controller.

In my controller I return:

```
public ActionResult ListCollege()
{
    return View(db.Colleges.ToList());
}
```

And the in the View I set the model as:

```
@model IEnumerable<CollegeApp.Models.DataModels.College>
```

But that's clearly not the right way to populate a DropDownListFor helper.

I've been doing a bit of reading and I wasn't exactly sure of the role of the `new SelectList` as the second argument in the `DropDownListFor` which is meant to be of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

And I don't quite get how this `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is passed from the model/controller to the view.

Thanks

Comment: SelectedList is the term you need to search about and learn how to use it.

Comment: You haven't shown the thing you are having a problem with - creating the DropDownListFor. The rest of it looks fine, your view receives a list in the model.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().CollegeName, .... That's as far as I got but that doesn't look right...

Comment: A quick search would give you result. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: So public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems is obviously what I am after. Thanks. I'm sure the guys at Microsoft know what they're doing...but it does seem a bit of work to setup a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use The `DropDownListFor` helper method effectively, you need to use a property of your view model to pass as the expression parameter, which will be a lambda expression. The helper will build the SELECT element with `name` and `Id` attribute values matching to that property name. The second parameter of the helper is a collection of `SelectListItem` , which will be used as the source data to build the options for the dropdown.

So in your case, create a view model which has 2 properties, one for the collection and one for the selected value

```
public class CollageSelectionVm
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Collages { set;get;}
   public int SelectedCollage { set;get;}
}
```

And in your GET action, create an object of this view model, load the `Collages` collection property and send that object to the view

```
public ActionResult ListCollege()
{
    var vm = new CollageSelectionVm () ;
    vm.Collages = db.Collages
                    .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                                    Text=x.Name })
                    .ToList();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now in the view,which is strongly typed to your view model, you will use the `DropDownListFor` helper

```
@model CollageSelectionVm

@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedCollage , Model.Collages , "Select one")
```